# Como randomizar os valores de um objeto em java

Tags: java

Estou construindo um programa de jogo de cartas, no qual em um determinado momento ele deverá misturar as cartas e pegar a que está na posição 0, mas não consigo fazer isso. Segue o código:

```
public class Baralho {
Carta[] cartas = new Carta[52];
String[] naipes = {"Copas", "Espada", "Ouros", "Paus"};
String[] nomes = {"As", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};
String coringa;
Random aleatorio = new Random();
public Baralho() {
    int cont = 0;
    for (String naipe : naipes) {
        for (String nome : nomes) {
            Carta cartas = new Carta();
            cartas.setNaipe(naipes);
            cartas.setNome(nomes);
            this.cartas[cont] = cartas;
            this.embaralha(naipes);
            cont++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(cartas);//Teste
}
public void embaralha(String[] carta) {//Esta parte aqui!
    aleatorio.naipes();
}
public void daCarta() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cartas.length; i++) {
        if (cartas[0] == null) {
            break;
        }else {
            System.out.println(cartas[0]);
        }
    }
}
public boolean temCarta() {
    boolean TouF = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < cartas.length; i++) {
        if (cartas[i] != null) {
            TouF = false;
        }else {
            TouF = true;
        }
    }
    return TouF;
}
public void imprime() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cartas.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(cartas[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `Random` é uma classe do seu projeto ou de uma dependência do mesmo?

Comment: Random é uma classe

Comment: Inclua ela na sua pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [shuffle()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) da classe Collections. Ele recebe uma lista como parâmetro. Como você tem um array, utilize o `Arrays.asList()` para converter o array em lista.

Supondo que você tenha um array chamado *baralho*, tudo o que você precisa para embaralhá-lo é usar:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(baralho));
```

O exemplo abaixo vai imprimir um valor aleatório cada vez que o programa é executado:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] baralho = new String[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < baralho.length; i++) {
        baralho[i] = String.valueOf(i);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(baralho));
    System.out.println(baralho[0]);
}
```

Se essa resposta lhe ajudou, marque-a como correta. ;)

Fonte: [Random shuffling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)